# ES6 'async' not defined or ES9 'arrow function not defined

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jshint

I am using JSHint in Eclipse.  When I configure for `"esversion": 6`, the arrow function warnings go away, but instead I get async and await warnings.  When I set esversion to 8 or 9, the async and await warnings go away, but arrow function warnings re-appear.

I would think arrow functions are supported in ES9. Is there a way to get JSHint to allow both?

```json
{
    // == Enforcing Options ===============================================
    //
    // These options tell JSHint to be more strict towards your code. Use
    // them if you want to allow only a safe subset of JavaScript, very
    // useful when your codebase is shared with a big number of developers
    // with different skill levels. Was all true.
     
    "bitwise" : true, // Prohibit bitwise operators (&, |, ^, etc.).
    "curly" : true, // Require {} for every new block or scope.
    "eqeqeq" : true, // Require triple equals i.e. `===`.
    "forin" : true, // Tolerate `for in` loops without `hasOwnPrototype`.
    "immed" : true, // Require immediate invocations to be wrapped in parens e.g. `( function(){}() );`
    "latedef" : true, // Prohibit variable use before definition.
    "newcap" : true, // Require capitalization of all constructor functions e.g. `new F()`.
    "noarg" : true, // Prohibit use of `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee`.
    "noempty" : true, // Prohibit use of empty blocks.
    "nonew" : true, // Prohibit use of constructors for side-effects.
    "plusplus" : false, // Prohibit use of `++` & `--`. //coding style related only
    "regexp" : true, // Prohibit `.` and `[^...]` in regular expressions.
    "undef" : true, // Require all non-global variables be declared before they are used.
    "strict" : false, // Require `use strict` pragma in every file.
    "trailing" : true, // Prohibit trailing whitespaces.
    "esversion" : 9,
    
    // == Relaxing Options ================================================
    //
    // These options allow you to suppress certain types of warnings. Use
    // them only if you are absolutely positive that you know what you are
    // doing. Was all false.
    "asi" : false, // Tolerate Automatic Semicolon Insertion (no semicolons).
    "boss" : false, // Tolerate assignments inside if, for & while. Usually conditions & loops are for comparison, not assignments.
    "debug" : false, // Allow debugger statements e.g. browser breakpoints.
    "eqnull" : false, // Tolerate use of `== null`.
    //"es5" : true, // Allow EcmaScript 5 syntax. // es5 is default https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1411
    "esnext" : false, // Allow ES.next (ECMAScript 6) specific features such as `const` and `let`.
    "evil" : false, // Tolerate use of `eval`.
    "expr" : false, // Tolerate `ExpressionStatement` as Programs.
    "funcscope" : false, // Tolerate declarations of variables inside of control structures while accessing them later from the outside.
    "globalstrict" : false, // Allow global "use strict" (also enables 'strict').
    "iterator" : false, // Allow usage of __iterator__ property.
    "lastsemic" : false, // Tolerat missing semicolons when the it is omitted for the last statement in a one-line block.
    "laxbreak" : false, // Tolerate unsafe line breaks e.g. `return [\n] x` without semicolons.
    "laxcomma" : true, // Suppress warnings about comma-first coding style.
    "loopfunc" : false, // Allow functions to be defined within loops.
    "maxerr" : 1000, // This options allows you to set the maximum amount of warnings JSHint will produce before giving up. Default is 50.
    "multistr" : false, // Tolerate multi-line strings.
    "onecase" : false, // Tolerate switches with just one case.
    "proto" : false, // Tolerate __proto__ property. This property is deprecated.
    "regexdash" : false, // Tolerate unescaped last dash i.e. `[-...]`.
    "scripturl" : false, // Tolerate script-targeted URLs.
    "smarttabs" : false, // Tolerate mixed tabs and spaces when the latter are used for alignmnent only.
    "shadow" : false, // Allows re-define variables later in code e.g. `var x=1; x=2;`.
    "sub" : false, // Tolerate all forms of subscript notation besides dot notation e.g. `dict['key']` instead of `dict.key`.
    "supernew" : false, // Tolerate `new function () { ... };` and `new Object;`.
    "validthis" : false, // Tolerate strict violations when the code is running in strict mode and you use this in a non-constructor function.
    
    // == Environments ====================================================
    //
    // These options pre-define global variables that are exposed by
    // popular JavaScript libraries and runtime environments—such as
    // browser or node.js. TODO JSHint Documentation has more, but it is not clear since what JSHint version they appeared 
    "browser" : false, // Standard browser globals e.g. `window`, `document`.
    "couch" : false, // Enable globals exposed by CouchDB.
    "devel" : false, // Allow development statements e.g. `console.log();`.
    "dojo" : false, // Enable globals exposed by Dojo Toolkit.
    "jquery" : false, // Enable globals exposed by jQuery JavaScript library.
    "mootools" : false, // Enable globals exposed by MooTools JavaScript framework.
    "node" : true, // Enable globals available when code is running inside of the NodeJS runtime environment.
    "nonstandard" : false, // Define non-standard but widely adopted globals such as escape and unescape.
    "phantom" : false, //?since version? This option defines globals available when your core is running inside of the PhantomJS runtime environment.
    "prototypejs" : false, // Enable globals exposed by Prototype JavaScript framework.
    "rhino" : false, // Enable globals available when your code is running inside of the Rhino runtime environment.
    "worker" : false, //?since version? This option defines globals available when your code is running inside of a Web Worker.
    "wsh" : false, // Enable globals available when your code is running as a script for the Windows Script Host.
    "yui" : false, //?since version? This option defines globals exposed by the YUI JavaScript framework.
    
    // == JSLint Legacy ===================================================
    //
    // These options are legacy from JSLint. Aside from bug fixes they will
    // not be improved in any way and might be removed at any point.
    "nomen" : false, // Prohibit use of initial or trailing underbars in names.
    "onevar" : false, // Allow only one `var` statement per function.
    "passfail" : false, // Stop on first error.
    "white" : false, // Check against strict whitespace and indentation rules.
    
    // == Undocumented Options ============================================
    //
    // While Michael have found these options in [example1][2] and [example2][3] (already gone 404)
    // they are not described in the [JSHint Options documentation][4].
     
    "predef" : [ // Extra globals.
        //"exampleVar",
        //"anotherCoolGlobal",
        //"iLoveDouglas"
        "Java", "JavaFX", "$ARG" //no effect
    ]
    //, "indent" : 2 // Specify indentation spacing
}
```

Edit, I did find a solution by adding async and await to the globals, but I think there is a better solution than that.

```
    
"globals" : {
        "async" : true,
        "await" : true,
        "describe" : true,
        "expect" : true,
        "it" : true
    },
```

Comment: I don't know for sure but I would set "esnext" to true and try it

Comment: I tried that and it broke everything.  The documentation is telling me that esnext is deprecated.  I'm going to browse around the github for jslint.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

- Install jshint through NPM and create a shell command to pipe the results of linting to a text file.  I have to open up that text file and use it's results to clean up code, but the results are much more relevant.

This leads me to believe that the issue is with the eclipse marketplace not having the latest build of jshint.  If that is so, then the solution really is to bug someone to volunteer their time to update the eclipse plugin, or do it myself..both of which I don't have the time for at the moment.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to think about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer.  Switched IDE's to VSCode and linter to ESLint.